# Convert Dask Series object into timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timestamp, dask

I have a huge Dask Dataframe which has a series dtype Object that contains a string that I want to convert into a timestamp (epoch unix time) so I can save it as an integer. Of the date, I am only interested in Day, Month and Year cause in my case, all the time is 00:00:00.

This is my series to convert:

[image: Series to convert]

This is what I tried at the end:

```py
df_leavetimes['DAYOFSERVICE'] = df_leavetimes['DAYOFSERVICE'].map_partitions(pd.to_datetime,format='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',meta = ('datetime64[ns]'))
```

Now I have this kind of data:

```
2018-01-01
```

How do I convert this into timestamp for the whole series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the `dask.dataframe.to_datetime` function, which should have the same API as the `pandas.to_datetime` function.